# change apk filename in gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use android build tools "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4" in my project. In my build script I rename the output apk which worked fine in the past but does not seem to be supported any more.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    def filename = "foo-${variant.baseName}-${variant.versionName}-(${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}).apk"

    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                filename
        )
    }
}
```

Now the propery I am trying to change became immutable:

> Error: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=stageDebug, filters=[]}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.

Is there a new or an alternate way how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grade Plugin 3-alpha1 outputFile causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044031/grade-plugin-3-alpha1-outputfile-causes-error)

Comment: The error I get is actually different and the provided solution does not work for me. Seems to be a new issue in the alpha-4. Edited my sample to reflect that the solution from the official doc does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239235/android-gradle-3-0-0-alpha2-plugin-cannot-set-the-value-of-read-only-property

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `each` -> to `all`
2. Change `output.outputFile` -> to `outputFileName`

before:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def finalVersionCode =v10000 + versionCode
        output.versionCodeOverride = finalVersionCode
        output.outputFile = new File(
             output.outputFile.parent,       output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk","-${finalVersion}.apk"))
    }
}
```

after:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def finalVersionCode = 10000 + versionCode
        output.versionCodeOverride = finalVersionCode
        outputFileName = new File(
             output.outputFile.parent,
             outputFileName.replace(".apk", "-${finalVersionCode}.apk"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add e.g. `versionName` to apk by adding

```
 setProperty("archivesBaseName", archivesBaseName + "-" + versionName)
```

in `defaultConfig` closure.